# Is there a way to uncheck a checkbox if it's counter equals to 0 with JavaScript or PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, frontend, backend

help me out on this one if it's possible. 
I have a product page and, on this page, people will be able to select a color to **remove** from the package and select how many items from determined kind they'll buy.
Example: I'm selling blouses and i have'em in 6 colors, red, blue, purple, yellow, orange and green, the customer would be able to choose one between those 6 or none of them and, they must fill some boxes with some infos, like, how many small blouses, or how many large blouses, etc. 
But my website will be mainly accessed by old fellas, so, i can't just do my thing and hope for the best like some would, i need to make this site really easy and almost out of the box to use it. 
Heres a printscreen of my web page

**-> printscreen: http://prntscr.com/ptdyu2**

Anyway, i need to uncheck everybox that has a 0 or smaller number in front of it. 
Is there a way for doing this?

```
    function(checkbox_validator){
var checkbox0 = document.getElementsByName(tmcp_checkbox_0_0_quantity)
    if (checkbox0 != True){
       //This is how much i've progressed on this part, only came until this point 
    }
}
```

Comment: your definition of `checkbox0` is an array. Yet you condition it as an element.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is possible. I created you a little example. Basically you will add a event listener for change on the input text fields. If the user types a number, or the value will change somehow, the event listener is getting triggered.

Based on the value you will set the specific checkbox checked or unchecked.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('inputItem1');
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkItem1');

input.addEventListener("input", update);

function update()
{
 //Now update the selector
  if (input.value > 0 )
  {
   checkbox.checked = true;
  }
  else
  {
   checkbox.checked = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="input" value="0" id="inputItem1">
  <input type="radio" id="checkItem1" name="checkItem1" value="">
</form>
```